# How to import javadoc jar when importing library in an application

Tags: java, spring, gradle, jar, javadoc

I have a library (named - 'MyLibrary') which I implemented using Java, Spring, and Gradle 6.6
In the Library code, I added some Javadocs. When I run `./gradlew javadoc` I can see build/lib folder getting created and index.html with proper comments being added, as expected.

Here are my other relevant changes in Library's **build.gradle**

```
java {
    withSourcesJar()
    withJavadocJar()
}

publishing {
    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
            from components.java
            artifactId archivesBaseName
            versionMapping {
                usage('java-api') {
                    fromResolutionOf('runtimeClasspath')
                }
                usage('java-runtime') {
                    fromResolutionResult()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    repositories {
        maven {
            name 'artifactory'
            url 'https://artifactory.abc.com/artifactory/libs-release'

            credentials {
                username = ARTIFACTORY_USERNAME
                password = ARTIFACTORY_PASSWORD
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the **artifactory**, I can see the library being published:

```
MyLibrary-lib-1.0.0-javadoc.jar             431.01 KB
MyLibrary-lib-1.0.0-javadoc.jar.sha512      128 bytes
MyLibrary-lib-1.0.0-sources.jar             7.09 KB
MyLibrary-lib-1.0.0-sources.jar.sha512      128 bytes
MyLibrary-lib-1.0.0.jar                     14.00 KB
MyLibrary-lib-1.0.0.jar.sha512              128 bytes
MyLibrary-lib-1.0.0.module                  4.18 KB
MyLibrary-lib-1.0.0.module.sha512           128 bytes
MyLibrary-lib-1.0.0.pom                     1.72 KB
MyLibrary-lib-1.0.0.pom.sha512              128 bytes
```

Now, in another application (written in Java, gradle 4.10.2), I have imported my library-MyLibrary.

**Application's build.gradle**:

```
dependencies {
  implementation('com.abc:MyLibrary-lib:1.0.0')
}

jar {
    enabled = true
}

bootJar {
    archiveClassifier.set('app')
}
```

Now, in the application's **External libraries**, I can see ONLY `MyLibrary-lib-1.0.0-sources.jar` is getting imported, **not** the `MyLibrary-lib-1.0.0-javadoc.jar`
Because of this, I'm not able to see Javadoc in the application, when I hover over the classes/methods of LLibrary in the application.

Note - I'm using IntelliJ and Mac.

Can someone please guide me what am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

You could generate your IntelliJ configuration for the application using MyLibrary-lib with gradle as well. The IDEA plugin page at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/idea_plugin.html describes how to do that and states that javadoc files will then be imported ("considered") as well.